# Windows Service wait until computer is ready

Tags: c#, windows-services, startup

I have a windows service that often fails when I restart my computer and I do not know exactly where. (I surround everything on a try catch block and I never hit the catch block!)

Anyways I think it is a time problem. If I make my process wait 15 seconds then it works fine. The service connects to a web service on a local network. What is the correct approach of initializing my service. Some computers are faster than others so one computer might need a 5 second delay and others may require a 25 seconds delay. What will be the most appropiate way of solving this problem?

what I am doing right now is on a while loop I try to connect to a local web service hosted on a the local network. If I am not able to connect I try again on the next 30 seconds. I am logging my data to a file and for some reason my service keeps running and it throws no exceptions.Every 30 seconds I should see a new line saying "attempting to connect" on my log but I dont get that line! Also I get no exceptions! If I go see the service on Task Manager,  Windows 7 says that the service is running. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your service is likely dependent on another service on the system that is started yet.  Windows has built in support for this by allowing you specify other services your service depends on.  I would suggest maybe setting your service to be dependent on the "Workstation" service.